# Jquery binding event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<img id="sun" href="logo.jpg"/>
```

How do I use JQuery to bind it so that when "sun" gets clicked, something happens?
I just want bind onclick to sun.

Comment: What is sun in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If sun is an id,

```
$('#sun').click( function(eo) {
    // your code here
});
```

if sun is a class,

```
$('.sun').click( function(eo) {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming "sun" is an element with the id "sun".

```
$("#sun").click(function(){
  alert("I was clicked!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If Sun is an id:

```
$("#sun").click(function(ev){
    // this refers to the dom element
    alert("I was clicked!");
    return false
});
```

Perhaps it is class:

```
$(".sun").click(function(ev){
    // this refers to the dom element
    alert("I was clicked!");
    return false
});
```

Or maybe a class, and the element may be created well after page load - eg via AJAX or DOM manipulation.

```
$(".sun").live('click',function(ev){
    // this refers to the dom element
    alert("I was clicked!");
    return false
});
```

JQuery API references:

- selectors http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
- .click() http://api.jquery.com/click/
- .live() http://api.jquery.com/live/